# How to decouple room entity

Tags: android, android-room

I have room entity like this

```
@Entity(tableName = "AppUser",
        indices = {@Index(value = {"UserId", "UserName"}, unique = true)})
public class AppUser  {

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @ColumnInfo(name = "UserId")
    public int id;

    public AppUser(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

}
```

What I want to do is to later add additional column to existing table by extending `AppUser` class . Something like following

```
public class ExtendedUser extends AppUser {

    public ExtendedUser(int id) {
        super(id);
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    @ColumnInfo(name = "address")
    String address;
}
```

So later if someone wants to modify the table , they do not need to modify `AppUser` , rather they would simply extend it .

Can I achieve it ?

Comment: Did you add the Entity annotation above ExtendedUser as you did in AppUser?

Comment: why you want to extend?  you should either add columns in existing class or use "Embedded" annotation

Comment: @acarlstein no , I am afraid that, it may create another table .

Comment: @ZaidMirza , actually I do not want any other developer to edit the base class, what I all want is to when user need to add another column they can do it in separate file.

Comment: @mW3 `Embedded` can help you in this.

Comment: @ZaidMirza it would be very helpful , if you kindly share some example .